# if mail is sent then why it's not in sent list?

Tags: php, email

In php we send a mail using `mail` function. I've two questions in my mind.
  Here my question is related to webmail. If we have a webmail e.g. info@abc.com and we send mail in php using that mail  `mail('to','Subject','Message','From:info@abc.com')`.

- Is the mail actually send by info@abc.com ?
- If mail is sent successfully then why it's not displaying in sent list of the sender ?

I'm still searching on the internet about it but i didn't found any useful answer yet.
can anyone clear my doubts ??

Comment: Generally php sends mail using internal mail program, and not your mail server - so that is why you dont see mail in 'sent' list.
If you want to use your external mail server - you have to implement its API or whatever it has ;)

Comment: send yourself an email and see for yourself ;-)

Comment: what makes you think that apache and/or php have access to the mail spool of the `from` user?

Comment: @Fred-ii-  already tried and then i asked this question. :)

Comment: look at the headers, they tell all

Comment: @Fred-ii- what is in it ?? I don't understand. Please elaborate.